# TypeScript syntax for creating resources

Tags: typescript, syntax

apologies for the basic question.
I'm new to TypeScript and want to know if there is any difference between the following code snippets:

```
    .... some code above ...

    const variable = myLibrary.fromAsset(this, "MyResource", {
        libSettings: this.libResources,
        target: this.libResources.target,
        runDef: getRunDef(
            props.account,
            props.region,
            props.domain
        ),
      });

    .... some code below ...
```

AND

```
    .... some code above ...

    myLibrary.fromAsset(this, "MyResource", {
        libSettings: this.libResources,
        target: this.libResources.target,
        runDef: getRunDef(
            props.account,
            props.region,
            props.domain
        ),
      });

    .... some code below ...
```

From my basic understanding, I know that the 1st snippet will create the resource and store it in a variable named `variable`, whereas the 2nd one will create it directly during runtime.

My question is- Does the 1st implementation also show up in development account like the 2nd one? (all the resources are created in the development account) Or do I have to somehow change the implementation and declare it using something like `this.variable = myLibrary.fromAsset( ..... )`?

Reason I'm asking this is because now I need to use this resource to create some more resources so I need to have a reference for it.

Comment: "*Does the 1st implementation also show up in development account like the 2nd one?*" this is not a question about TS. It is related to whatever library/SDK/API/whatever you are using. TS just dictates what code is valid. You're talking about what the code *does*. There are no development (or any) accounts in TS.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing it out.